# Fetch freezes after react-native app comes back from suspended state on IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, fetch, react-native-ios

I'm developing a react-native app, and we noticed something strange. When the app comes back from suspended state (it doesn't happen from normal background state I think), often, the fetch freezes afterwards.

To trigger it, put on battery saver (I think it will make the app go to suspended state a lot quicker), then put the app in the background, do some other stuff on your phone for a minute or 5-10, open the app again and use it.

In our case we navigated to an other screen which tried to fetch three lists of objects at the same time from the backend. In the backend, we noticed only one call coming through, and the `Promise.all(...)` on the three calls never gets resolved or catched. So there is no error either. Afterwards all calls work again and the problem seems to be gone. So it's a one time issue.

This never happens when not coming from suspended state.

This is extremely hard to debug, since when the app goes to suspended state, the debugger is disconnected.

We haven't tested this yet on Android, it could be that the problem exists there as well.

My gut feeling tells me, it has something to so with the internal networking of IOS or the fetch library of RN. (e.g. when reconnecting to wifi, coming from 4G or something)

Has someone experienced the same problem already or has more insights on why this is happening or how to solve this? (e.g. use a time-out and retry mechanism, which I would like to prevent, force a api call on state change to active - although react-native can't detect the suspended state)

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Forgot to add: we're using react-native 54, but are in the process of updating to 57. I'll report back if the issue is still happening on 57...

**EDIT 2:**
Atm, we solved it by doing to the calls after each other instead of the at the same time (so fetch().then(fetch().then(fetch())) which seems to resolve the issue. So yet again, doing the calls at the same time, never fails normally, only after a suspended state of the app.